# Pool pump keeps tripping breaker

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, pump

I installed a new pool pump today, only to find out that when it runs - it draws around 25-28A causing the breaker to trip.

The power rating on the motor is only 13A. What is going on?

Comment: Sometimes pumps, motors, etc. can be wired up for 120V or for 240V and if they are configured incorrectly some wacky things can happen. Double-check everything, and if you aren't 100% sure, upload pictures.

Comment: Is the pump actually pumping ? Are there in/out valves that you forgot to open. Open the vent valve on the filter unit. Most pump have start mode going in to high RPM when there is not enough water.

Comment: Can you give us the name plate info on the motor? I believe manassehkatz is right + as a 120v will draw 2x a 240v motor and many motors the stator coils are in parallel fro 120v and in series for 240v so if you read the 240v amperage and it was not configured correctly it would draw more (the other way around it smokes the coil though) so they are many times pre wired 240 so the motor won’t go up in smoke.@manassehkatz wrote that up as an answer it makes more sense and at 2x is just about right.

Comment: are there 2 circuit barkers for the pump linked together.

Comment: Is the motor shaft able to turn as it's supposed to?  A stalled (locked) rotor would cause this too. But I agree with Ed and Manassehkatz, motor mis-jumpering would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a motor/pump is drawing excess power, something is jammed.

Either the pump is defective, was put in wrong, or it has sucked something in besides water.  Like your sock your dryer lost.

It is like putting a stick in a bike wheel, you keep pushing harder with your feet till you stop, the stick breaks, or the wheel breaks

Comment: Jammed is one of (at least) 3 possibilities. Mis-wired has already been mentioned. Excessive flow is a third, though not terribly likely for a pool pump (a common error in well pump mis-application or mis-installation, though.)

Comment: A piece of styrofoam had broken off and jammed the impeller during shipping! Mystery solved!

Answer (score 2):

Look for the name plate on the motor and check the wiring diagram (if it has one) to see if the motor can be wired for either 120 or 240 volts. If so, you need to disconnect power and open the motor's wiring access plate to confirm the appropriate connections. If wired for 120 but powered by 240, the breaker will pop immediately.

The plate and diagram may look something like this.

[image: photo from thepatriotwoodworker.com]